# Shopware 6 : [Error] Call to a member function getStorageName() on null

Tags: database, migration, shopware, shopware6

I want migrate some tables into Shopware 6 database. When I run this commande line

```
bin/console dal:create:schema
```

I get this error : **[Error] Call to a member function getStorageName() on null**.
How can I solve this bug ? Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only one instance I can think of where this error might occur. It must be introduced by a plugin since this error would be caught before any release in the core.

There is a new `EntityDefinition` or `EntityExtension` (Definition A) which adds a `ManyToOneAssociationField`. The association references another `EntityDefinition` (Definition B). Definition B has implemented [the `isVersionAware` method](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/7cd211989efab02efa1691e92ac8e480721dea32/src/Core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/EntityDefinition.php#L332) to return `true`. If definition A now misses to add a `ReferenceVersionField` for definition B as well, this is when the field to retrieve the storage name from would remain to be `null`, causing the error.

You can find the [corresponding lines of code in the `SchemaGenerator`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/4f702cf266cd97ac1164b89331c664e7ed4d8662/src/Core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/SchemaGenerator.php#L260).

For a correct implementation you can find the [`OrderAddressDefinition`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/4f702cf266cd97ac1164b89331c664e7ed4d8662/src/Core/Checkout/Order/Aggregate/OrderAddress/OrderAddressDefinition.php#L68) which adds both a `ManyToOneAssociationField`, as well as a `ReferenceVersionField` for the `OrderDefinition` (which is version aware). If you were to remove the `ReferenceVersionField` you could reproduce this error without any plugins as well.

Either look at all the instances of `EntityDefinition`/`EntityExtension` within the plugins or try deactivating plugins one by one and try creating the schema again, until you find the plugin causing the error.

Comment: In my case this was caused by copying a `OneToManyAssociationField` from another entity definition and forgetting to also change the associated column name. E.g:

`(new OneToManyAssociationField('authormedia', AuthorMediaDefinition::class, 'author_id'))->addFlags(new CascadeDelete())->addFlags(new ApiAware())`

Instead of "author_id" I had "blog_id" which was incorrect.

The error is super hard to fix because the message is misleading and/or does not provide enough information for someone inexperienced to fix it. Unfortunately a lot of time wasted because of such exceptions.